How can I update row by row the newly created column REVENUE based on the output of a SELECT statement?
I have created the column named Revenue in the Sales_Data table and I need to update it based on the output of the following query:
SELECT
    (Sales_Data.OrderQuantity * Product_Lookup.ProductPrice) AS Revenue 
FROM
    Sales_Data
INNER JOIN 
    Product_Lookup ON Product_Lookup.ProductKey = Sales_Data.ProductKey

As you can see from the above in order to calculate the Revenue I have joined the Sales_Data and Product_Lookup tables through ProductKey PK and FK. The result of the above is 56,046 rows which I need to insert in the Revenue column of the Sales_data table.
I reckon that I should use a subquery but unfortunately thus far I have not been successful.
Could anyone here help me out to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.
I have unsuccessfully tried the following query:
UPDATE Sales_Data
SET Revenue = (SELECT
                   (Sales_Data.OrderQuantity * Product_Lookup.ProductPrice) AS Revenue 
               FROM
                   Sales_Data
               INNER JOIN
                   Product_Lookup ON Product_Lookup.ProductKey = Sales_Data.ProductKey)

I have got the below message:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the  subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.


Side note: Are you updating historic sales data? Product price typically changes over time, so you may need to investigate how historic prices are represented in your database and add logic to select the appropriate price for each sale.

Agree with @TN here, i'm not sure why you're adding a revenue into a sale table, there should be one already, also, how do you handle things like black friday discounts if you always take the price from the product. The sql is the least of the issues here

The way you are updating the column with a subquery, returns a row for each product (56,046 rows) in sales data, this is why returns the error of more than one value.
Try this instead
UPDATE s SET Revenue = s.OrderQuantity * p.ProductPrice
FROM Sales_Data s
INNER JOIN Product_Lookup p ON p.ProductKey = s.ProductKey


antonio_mg Thanks for your answer which worked fine. Very useful.

Also Siggemannen gave the correct answer
